# How to get creation or modified date of uploaded files(From local pc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to get last modified date of uploaded files without creating path on server.

Basically

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "QuestionForm", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select" />
}
```

Controller

```
    [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([Bind] QuestionModel modelVal)
 {
        var httpRequest = Request.Form;
         foreach (IFormFile uploadedFile in httpRequest.Files)
         {
             //Saving to database
         }

    }
```

After upload I'm saving files in database instead of server.
How can I  know uploaded files last modified date or creation date.

Edited= I'm uploading files from my local storage.

Comment: `"How can I can know uploaded files last modified date or creation date."` Not seeing if its existing files or new file. Could you please confirm are you checking for existing files whether is it modifed or not something like? In addition, please share more details.

Comment: local storage could contain a file or object... if it's a file, you can access this client-side.  Check File API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File  (looks like lastModified may be the only property you can get, though.)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get last modified date of uploaded files without creating
> path on server.

Well, we can get the file details information when it has written last time or modified using [`GetLastWriteTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastwritetime?view=net-7.0)  or [`GetCreationTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=net-7.0)  method.

Implementation:

Let's assume I have below files in my application:

[image]

Now, I would like to search `TestImage.jpg` when it was modified last time. As we can see it was modifid on `1-Jun-22:9.20am`. So let's implement on controller code snippet:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetFileInformation()
        {
            var fileName = "TestImage.jpg";
            var path =  Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ImageName/Cover", fileName);
            var lastModified =  System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
            return Ok();
        }
```

**Note**: Point that, here `"ImageName/Cover"` is refering the folder name where you would like to execute your search operation.

In addition, please check implementation details for more method based on your requirement:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Alternative Way:**

```
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = null;
            fi = new FileInfo(fileName);// Here pass the file you want to search
            var createdTime = fi.CreationTime;
            var lastAccessTime = fi.CreationTime;
            var lastWriteTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
```

**Note:** For more details you could [have a look on our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-get-information-about-files-folders-and-drives)

Comment: In my scenario, my images and files are uploaded from local storage.

Comment: How are you uploading this into local storage( Local storage means what do you mean, you application drive?) share that part, In addition, as you are saying you are uploading from local storage then where you would like to check creation or file writing time? In local storage or where?

Comment: as I mentioned I'm uploading to database. So before saving/uploading to database I want to check that file creation or modification date .

Comment: Bro, you haven't read my answer clearly, if you want to know the created,last access and file writing information, we need the location, means where the file is now residing. If the file location is unknow no one in the world retrive the information. So, what is the path of your file, no matter local or what, if it is within the machine where th application is running we can get the information.

Comment: Knowing file path or location is mandatory for getting file read/write information this is the main point. Hope now the explanation seems more clear and transparent

Comment: sorry if I sounded rude . Is there way to find uploading files(From local pc) created or modified date?

Comment: Never mind man, yes try alternative way, just pass the file name with ext

Comment: Ok tried your alternative way but it return all dates with default time(01-01-1601).

Comment: Would you kindly Update your question with your `files(From local pc)` structure with clear screnshot and how you have implemented the code. I will check and update you tomorrow, Now I am about to leave mate.